# AssertJ, Want to do pre and post for each assertThat

Tags: java, junit4, assertj

I'm Using SoftAssertions in **AssertJ** and Java 8,

For Ex:

SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();

softly.assertThat(mansion.guests()).as("Living Guests").isEqualTo(7);

softly.assertThat(mansion.kitchen()).as("Kitchen").isEqualTo("clean");

softly.assertThat(mansion.library()).as("Library").isEqualTo("clean");

softly.assertAll();

I want to do the Pre & Post operations for each **assertThat**() statement.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre/post hooks in AssertJ assertions.

By curiosity, why would you need them ?

Comment: Because i'm  writing a Testing framework which will read the multiple Testcases from DB and looping through all Testcases. So for each iteration in a loop, i  want to perform the pre/post operations.